# apply special css background to cytoscape.js edge

Tags: javascript, css, cytoscape.js, cytoscape-web

I want to be able to specify/switch the direction of a cytoscape.js edge using css. The design I want to use is as such (the bottom design): [image: line design] Is it possible to set the style of a cytoscape edge to the following on demand?

Answer (score 1):

As far as I can tell, you can't only show the edge arrows and not the edge itself. Apart from that, it's only possible to place an edge arrow at the start, middle and end of an edge (so not 4 of them)

[Edge arrows](http://js.cytoscape.org/#style/edge-arrow)

[Edge endpoints](http://js.cytoscape.org/#style/edge-endpoints)

Comment: I actually meant the background of the edge itself followed a gradient similar to what I've drawn out. But now that you mention those APIs I do have a different question for you: is it possible to change the direction of an edge?

Comment: judging by the API, I doubt that's possible.
And while you can't change the edge's internal source & target node (apart from removing the edge and making a new one), you can choose whether your edge arrows target the source or target node

e.g. {'source-arrow-shape': 'triangle',

'target-arrow-shape': 'square'}

Comment: Thank you this is perfect!! One final question: do you know how to clean up the source pointing arrow? http://i.imgur.com/OiGqTsg.png

Comment: I don't appear to have this problem in my project. I suggest playing around with 'source-distance-from-node' http://js.cytoscape.org/#style/edge-endpoints

Comment: I don't really understand how you avoid that issue since the arrow is already at distance 0 from the node, it's just that the edge "leaks" past and causes that problem. Is there some sort of API to edit the distance the edge itself is away from the node?

Comment: so it seems that setting "inside-to-node" works, but then it overrides the source arrow's style, apparently only allowing one arrow.

Comment: 'source-distance-from-node' doest exactly what you're asking for.

Comment: I tried that, and it worked. Thank you for all your help!